# Always getting "Cannot read property 'style' of null" error and I dont see why

Tags: javascript, html

My .html file

```
  <span id="menu_start_random">Random</span>
  <span id="menu_start_prop">Custom</span>
```

My .js file

```
function menuToggle(action, id) {
  switch (action) {
    case true:
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
      break;
    case false:
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
      break;
  }
}

function doIt(mode)
{
  switch (mode) {
    case "random":
      menuToggle(false, "menu_start_custom");
      break;

    case "custom":
      menuToggle(false, "menu_start_prop");
      break;
  }
}
```

When I now call the function `doIt("random")` I always get the error "Cannot read property 'style' of null" for any reason, but `doIt("custom")` works just as planned. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: You are looking for an element with id "menu_start_custom" ... And there is no corresponding element with that id in your html

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't have `menu_start_custom` element.

```js
function menuToggle(action, id) {
  switch (action) {
    case true:
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
      break;
    case false:
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
      break;
  }
}

function doIt(mode)
{
  switch (mode) {
    case "random":
      menuToggle(false, "menu_start_custom");
      break;

    case "custom":
      menuToggle(false, "menu_start_prop");
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="menu_start_custom">Random</span>
<span id="menu_start_prop">Custom</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your html

```
<span id="menu_start_random">Random</span>
```

And in your js

```
menuToggle(false, "menu_start_custom");
```

So menu_start_custom doesn't exist